# Display ColdFusion Query Output in a Formatted Table

Tags: coldfusion

Let me begin by saying that I'm a novice at ColdFusion and trying to learn so please bear with me.

I work in an apartment complex that caters to students from the local college.  We have one, two and four bedroom apartments.  Each room in an apartment is leased to an individual student.   What I want to do is populate an HTML table with all the people in a room.  My query is working and pulling all the relevant data but what is happening is that each person is being split out to their own HTML table instead of all the people in a room being put into the same table.  Here is an example:

What I want

[image: expected image]

What is happening:

[image: actual image]

Here is my code:

```
    <!---Begin data table--->
    <cfoutput query = "qryGetAssignments">
    <div class="datagrid">
    <table> 
      <tr><td align="right"><strong>#RoomType#</strong></td></tr>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#RoomNumber#</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td><strong>#Bed#</strong> 
            | #FirstName# #LastName# :: #StudentNumber# 
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
     </cfoutput>
```

I know why the output is coming out like it is, I just don't know how to fix it.  I want there to be four residents in one table for a four bedroom apartment, two residents in a table for a two bedroom, and so on.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:**
Sorry about the confusion. Here is a full pic of what I'm going for:

[image: Expected - more detailed]

Comment: you probably don't want your whole table inside the portion that is looping over the rows, otherwise you'll get a table for each row rather than a row for each row.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your comment.  I tried moving the <cfoutput> tag down inside the table.  When I do that, I get the same "split out" output only the table is formatted vertically with each entry on top of the other instead of a three column page format like I'm going for.

Comment: 3 column page format? i don't see how your first image represents that.

Comment: hmm... are you trying to distribute the 4 people across multiple rooms based on how many people can fit in each room? if that's the case, then.... we need a lot more information, such as how you are generating this query, because in it's current format, it's relatively useless for solving your problem.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  Here is a full pic of what I'm going for. [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/JfWcbNo)

Comment: Take a look at the [<cfoutput group="..">](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff6.html) feature. You could easily use it generate one table, or div, per roomNumber. See [example](http://coldfusionexamples.com/2010/11/01/displaying-a-grouped-query-using-nested-cfoutput-tags-in-coldfusion/). To display three tables/divs per row, look into the [MOD](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/665-and-on-the-seventh-row-mod-created-1-and-it-was-good.htm)  operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need, assuming your query is properly ordered by roomType, for the `<cfoutput group="">` to work.

```
<!---Begin data table--->
<cfoutput query="qryGetAssignments" group="roomType">
  <div class="datagrid"><!--- If this isn't needed to style the tables, it can be moved outside the loop --->
    <table> 
      <tr><td align="right"><strong>#qryGetAssignments.roomType#</strong></td></tr>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#qryGetAssignments.roomNumber#</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <strong>#qryGetAssignments.bed#</strong> 
            <cfoutput><!--- this output here will loop over rows for that groupby --->
              | #FirstName# #LastName# :: #StudentNumber# 
            </cfoutput>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</cfoutput>
```

I've also scoped your query variables, at least I believe they are variables from a query.

Answer (score 0):

That should work except it might need to be grouped by "roomNumber" such as N108.